# Docker - error al iniciar contenedor

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Tengo dos contenedores para un proyecto de laravel uno con mysql y otro con apache, al arrancar el de mysql me da error.

Lo primero que hago es parar todos los contenedores con el comando  "**docker-compose down**" y por pantalla me sale esto

```
Stopping backend-forms_app_1 ... done
Removing backend-forms_app_1 ... done
Removing database                 ... done
Removing network backend-bringforms_default
```

Y si realizo un "docker-compose

```
Creating network "backend-forms_default" with the default driver
Creating database ...
Creating database                 ... error
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

Creating backend-forms_app_1 ... done

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint database (ee9216527529596af152a5e210b6f8a90e46badd3e29bb8f4c9e024b0da1cc2e): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3307 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**Fichero docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravelapp
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Comment: te esta dando error a qcrear la base de datos, probablemente tienes que cambiar tu docker compose puedes agregarlo

Comment: Adjunto mi fichero docker-compose en el post principal

Comment: Te está diciendo que ya tienes a alguien oyendo por el 3307. `docker ps` y revisa si hay otro contenedor corriendo o si no has detenido otras pruebas

Comment: te funciono mi respuesta?

Comment: @Alfabravo el docker-compose deberia levantar una red "backend-forms_default" lo que creo que debe pasar esta explicado en la respuesta

Comment: @JackNavaRow de acuerdo. Por eso es que voté positiva tu respuesta. Otra cosa es que el OP desapareció esta semana xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que se esta ejecutando primero la imagen `app` y luego la imagen de base de datos; la solucion para esto es sencilla debes agregar a la construccion de la imagen `app` que dependa de la ejecucion de la base de datos algo como `depends:db` el ejemplo completo a continuacion:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    depends_on: 
      - db         
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravelapp
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

> [Te invito a leer mas en la Documentación](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Comment: Gracias, lo he resuelto. Muchas gracias